# Can you move a mouse position from a job?

Tags: powershell, mouse

I am attempting to move the mouse using `Start-Job`, however it doesn't work, though the job itself is completed. Is there a way to move the mouse as part of a job or is this something that isn't possible? Couldn't find an answer online.

```
function moveMouseJob
{
    [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$($[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 100),$($[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y)"
}

Clear-Host

Start-Job $function:moveMouseJob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in your code - a missing 's' in Forms. It should read:

```
[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = $mousePosition
```

Following [this advice](https://flamingkeys.com/moving-the-mouse-cursor-with-windows-powershell/) I was able to move the mouse cursor 100 pixels to the right with this code that casts a string like "1024,768" to a System.Drawing.Point:

```
[windows.forms.Cursor]::Position = "$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 100),$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.Y)"
```

EDIT: You're right about requiring the Windows.Forms reference in the job - makes sense since it's a new runspace. The cursor moved once I added it. The Receive-Job line wasn't necessary, but may be useful for your purposes.

```
$job = start-job {
    [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [windows.forms.Cursor]::Position = "$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 100),$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.Y)"
}
Receive-Job -Job $job
```

Comment: Even with the typo it still doesn't work, does moving the mouse work inside of a job or does it not?

Comment: You still have the typo in your question after the edit, which definitely doesn't work. But it seems like it doesn't work from a Job - I'm seeing the same behavior where the job completes without moving the cursor. 
`$job = start-job {[windows.forms.Cursor]::Position = "$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 100),$([windows.forms.Cursor]::Position.Y)"} `
Why is it necessary to use a Job instead of the line of code I provided? Are you trying to start the job using different credentials?

Comment: I'm not sure if I necessarily "NEED" to use a job but I need to have another thread where a form is running and I'm trying to move the mouse on it / control the mouse in order to calculate how the display on the form should look like. I'll likely look more into threading for powershell as currently I'm playing around and a job isn't likely the best way to go about it as it cannot move the mouse. If you have any ideas let me know.

Comment: Got it to work, needed to use `receive-job` as well as set `[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")` inside of the job or else it won't be loaded into it. Worked with: `$job = start-job -ScriptBlock {[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$([Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 100),$([Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y)"}` and `receive-job -job $job`, if you could edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh I guess receive job wasn't needed haha. Just needed a reference to the forms inside of it.